# Filter Json Data and fill it in the dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, filter

I am using PHP and I have JSON data in which I want to filter the `status=active` people and I want to store the `status=active` people into the dropdown.

So how to do it? Here is the JSON data below:

```
[
  {
    "username": "7291991451",
    "uid": "mfwUrskyhzVvzS16pS_a",
    "name": "Abhishek B",
    "status": "Active",
    "is_busy": true,
    "duty_day_bits": "1111111",
    "duty_start_time": null,
    "duty_end_time": null,
    "vehicle": null,
    "vehicle_type": null,
    "todays_mileage": 2244,
    "yesterdays_mileage": 30498,
    "created_at": " 3/05/2016  5:14:12PM",
    "merchant_address": null,
    "merchant_id": null
  },
  {
    "username": "7291991462",
    "uid": "G1knzKyuKoZK78CZySyA",
    "name": "Akash Gupta",
    "status": "Active",
    "is_busy": false,
    "duty_day_bits": "1111111",
    "duty_start_time": null,
    "duty_end_time": null,
    "vehicle": null,
    "vehicle_type": null,
    "todays_mileage": 0,
    "yesterdays_mileage": 0,
    "created_at": "18/05/2016  1:16:19PM",
    "merchant_address": null,
    "merchant_id": null
  },
  {
    "username": "7291991456",
    "uid": "ndHsmz-BvyXfjv42MTyd",
    "name": "Ankur Sagar",
    "status": "Archived",
    "is_busy": false,
    "duty_day_bits": "1111111",
    "duty_start_time": null,
    "duty_end_time": null,
    "vehicle": null,
    "vehicle_type": null,
    "todays_mileage": 0,
    "yesterdays_mileage": 0,
    "created_at": " 3/05/2016  5:36:00PM",
    "merchant_address": null,
    "merchant_id": null
  },
  {
    "username": "7503710039",
    "uid": "j-w2jxx14s6GgF_YkcFP",
    "name": "Annu Gupta",
    "status": "Archived",
    "is_busy": false,
    "duty_day_bits": "1111111",
    "duty_start_time": null,
    "duty_end_time": null,
    "vehicle": null,
    "vehicle_type": null,
    "todays_mileage": 0,
    "yesterdays_mileage": 0,
    "created_at": " 2/09/2016 12:59:13PM",
    "merchant_address": null,
    "merchant_id": null
  },
  {
    "username": "9599380369",
    "uid": "KarAFisqeRpcr_xtEhEB",
    "name": "Arun Kumar",
    "status": "Active",
    "is_busy": true,
    "duty_day_bits": "1111111",
    "duty_start_time": null,
    "duty_end_time": null,
    "vehicle": null,
    "vehicle_type": null,
    "todays_mileage": 0,
    "yesterdays_mileage": 0,
    "created_at": " 5/05/2016  1:30:33PM",
    "merchant_address": null,
    "merchant_id": null
  }]
```

Comment: Please share your PHP code as well.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) your json data:

```
$my_array = json_decode( $your_json_data );
```

After that run a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $my_array as $value ) {
    if( 'Active' === $value->status ){
        // do whatever you need
    }
}
```